# Modules lost upgrading to python 3.11

Tags: arm, python-import, python-3.11, jetson-xavier, tensorrt-python

I just installed python 3.11 and noticed modules are missing.
I am working on ARM, NVIDIA Jetson Xavier AGX, Jetpack 5.0.2 it comes with ubuntu 20.04 and python 3.8.

In python 3.8 I can run `import tensorrt`, but in python 3.11 I get `No module named "tensorrt"`

I tried

```
python3.8 -m pip freeze  > requirements.txt
python3.11 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But I quickly get:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorrt==8.4.1.5 (from versions: 0.0.1.dev5, 0.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorrt==8.4.1.5
```

Can python 3.11 use python3.8 modules, or do I have to install them with correct distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,
pybinding for 3.11 is something you can build for this purpose.

See: [TensorRT Python Bindings](https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/tree/release/8.4/python)

You can modify: [Tensorrt on Jetson with python 3.9](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/tensorrt-on-jetson-with-python-3-9/196131/9)

By

- [Installing python 3.11](https://www.debugpoint.com/install-python-3-11-ubuntu/) rather than compiling it
- Swap TensorRT 8.0 with 8.4
- Swap cmake 3.15.5 with 3.25.2